# what happens to a double pointer when it is passed to a function

Tags: c, stack, double-pointer

Im having some trouble understanding how the pass by value mechanism works in c with pointers. Here is my contrived example...

---

In my `main` function, I `malloc` a pointer to an array of `int`:

```
int ** checkMe;
checkMe = malloc(sizeof(int *) * 10);
```

I understand that this operation sets a side a block of 10 chunks of memory, each block big enough to hold the pointer to an `int` pointer. I receive back the pointer at the start of this block of 10 chunks.

I have another function that takes that double pointer as an argument:

```
void test2dArray(int ** arr, int size) {
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        // arr[i] = malloc(sizeof(int) * size);
        for (j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            arr[i][j] = i * j;
        }
    }
}
```

---

Whenever I leave the commented section as is, and try to `malloc` the space for the `int` in `main` like this:

```
int ** checkMe;
checkMe = malloc(sizeof(int *) * 10);

for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    checkMe[i] = malloc(sizeof(int));
}

test2dArray(checkMe, 10);
```

I get memory clobbering whenever I iterate `checkMe` after the `test2dArray` call in `main`.

**But** if I `malloc` the space for the `int` in `test2dArray` instead (by uncommenting the commented line above) and change my call from `main` to this:

```
int ** checkMe;
checkMe = malloc(sizeof(int *) * 10);

test2dArray(checkMe, 10);
```

the memory clobbering goes away and I can reference `checkMe` just fine after the function call.

---

I understand that `checkMe` is being passed into `test2dArray` by value. I think this means that the address that is returned by `checkMe = malloc(sizeof(int *) * 10);` is copied into the function.

I don't understand why the `int *`'s that `checkMe` stores gets lost if I don't `malloc` the space from within `test2dArray`

Comment: What do you mean by "clobbering"?

Comment: @Potatoswatter - is it the new term for "smashing" the stack?

Comment: What is sad, is that I did this incorrectly in both my project and my contrived example above. Thank you all for setting me straight on this ridiculously simple bug that I was making out into something much larger...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    checkMe[i] = malloc(sizeof(int));
}
```

You are only allocating memory for 1 `int` in each loop iteration. So you have an array of 10 pointers, each pointing to `sizeof(int)` bytes of memory.

```
test2dArray(checkMe, 10);
```

only works for arrays of 10 pointers pointing to at least `10*sizeof(int)` memory. You should change the line above to `checkMe[i] = malloc(sizeof(int)*10)`;

Answer (score 2):

When you are allocating in `main` you are not allocating for 10 integers,

```
checkMe[i] = malloc(sizeof(int));
```

change it to

```
checkMe[i] = malloc(sizeof(int) * 10);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your bug is the difference between this:

```
checkMe[i] = malloc(sizeof(int));
```

and this:

```
arr[i] = malloc(sizeof(int) * size); // size = 10
```